# Inverting Matrix in Prony's Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading Ankur Moitra's excellent lectures notes at http://people.csail.mit.edu/moitra/docs/bookex.pdf .

In Chapter4, the notes claim that a certain circulant matrix of fourier coefficients is invertible [left as exercise to reader, and I can't find the footnote]. I can not prove it. I'm also not convinced it's true. The pages are attached. Any pointers as to what I should read up on would be helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT: Images are high resolution. Click "open image in new tab".

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please replace the images with text of the part your question is about (i.e. don't use image for text).

Comment: @Kaveh: What are you referring to? Do you want me to (1) re-latex all 4 pages of math or (2) write the red image-text as text?

Comment: Remove the images and write your question completely in text.

Comment: I'm not going to do that. However, I solved the problem. Is there a way to delete it? (I don't see a "DELETE" button under "EDIT"). Thanks!